# Spring application to MQ authentification issue

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I'm writing a java app with a Listener to read messages from WebSphere MQ.

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="mqMessageListener" class="ru.mos.notification.controller.MQNotificationListener">
    <property name="mqwsUrl" value="${mqws.url}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapAction" value="${mqws.soapAction}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapStart" value="${mqws.soapStart}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapEnd" value="${mqws.soapEnd}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${mq.hostName}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mq.port}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${mq.queueManager}" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${mq.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mq.password}" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">       
    <property name="destinationName" value="${mq.destinationName}" />
    <property name="destinationResolver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />
    </property>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="mqMessageListener" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This is what causing problems:

```
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
```

If I remove this property everything work fine. Messages from my queue are read. But if I put this property I got the following error:

```
17:54:20,468  WARN DefaultMessageListenerContainer:821 - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'asurtst1qu' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'asurtst1mgr' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.31.197.247(1414)'. Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager you are connecting.
```

I need transaction manager to put message back to the queue if there's any errors. But i can't use it due this exception. Help me pls.

Comment: What is the error found on the queue manager error log (AMQERR01.LOG). If you are connecting to a qmgr version 7 and below, try removing the user and password from jmsConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transactionManager bean should ref jmsConnectionFactory not mqQueueConnectionFactory.